# Trying to delete a comment from a post in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

**I am currently trying to delete a comment from my database via a button in django template.
Model looks like this**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField
from profiles.models import UserProfile


class Post(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='user_posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=220, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="activity_post")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', blank=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='activity_likes', blank=True)
    like_count = models.BigIntegerField(default='0')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def liked_by_user(self):
        return self.likes.values_list('id', flat=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="user_comment")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment {self.body} by {self.name}"
```

**Delete function**

```
def delete_comment(request, post_id):
    users_comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, post=post_id)
    users_comment.delete()

    return redirect(reverse('activity'))
```

**URLS**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('like/', views.like, name='like'),
    path("add/", views.add_post, name="add_post"),
    path('edit/<int:post_id>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
    path('delete/<int:post_id>/', views.delete_post, name='delete_post'),
    path('edit_comment/<int:id>/', views.edit_comment, name='edit_comment'),
    path('delete_comment/<int:post_id>/', views.delete_comment, name='delete_comment'),
    path("activity/", views.PostList.as_view(), name="activity"),
    path('comment/<int:post_id>/', views.Comment.as_view(), name='comment'),
    path('searched_posts/', views.search_posts, name='searched_posts'),
    path('post/<int:post_id>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')
]
```

**here is the comment part that is showing the button.**

```
{%if comments %}
{% for comment in comments %}
{% if comment.user == request.user %}
{{comment.body}} :comment
{{comment.id}} id
<a class="btn tbn-success" href="{% url 'edit_comment' comment.id %}" aria-label="edit button">Edit</a>
<button class="btn btn-warning"><a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment.id %}">Delete</a></button>
{% endif %}

{% endfor%}
{% endif%}
```

**When I click delete i get an error**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7zlB.png)

**Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried a ton of different ways from online but nothing seems to work. can anyone point me in the right direction**

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can see is that your delete function uses post = post_id.

Every comment on a particular post will share that post foreign key, so if there is more than one comment on a post, you can't use get_or_404() - it's limited to returning 1 item.

The URL you create for your button is using comment.id so it makes sense to use that instead - this will make it easier to see what's happening.

urls.py

```
 path('delete_comment/<int:comment_id>/', views.delete_comment, name='delete_comment'),
```

views.py

```
def delete_comment(request, comment_id):
    users_comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    users_comment.delete()

    return redirect(reverse('activity'))
```